# Rails predictive search form suggestions with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I want to get predictive search suggestions in a drop-down menu, Google-style. I found Elasticsearch would be the way to go (is it?), however I am facing some problems while implementing it to my Rails app (running on Heroku, but that is not the problem - atleast not yet :).

My app is pretty straightforward. I have a model, view and controller for a "space", which resembles a room or a building in a campus. The database structure is really simple, it contains one table ("spaces") with details like name, code, address. I'd like any of these to be searchable.

I tried to implement Elasticsearch by this guide: http://crestcode.com/deploying-elasticsearch-on-heroku-with-rails-4/

So at the moment I have basically done step 4, but it does not work. These are my pieces of code, representing the parts that the guide told me to do (forgive the bad indentation):

*views/spaces/index.html.erb*

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "spaces", action: "show"}, method: "get", id: 'searchbox', class: "nifty_form") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Search for a building or a room:") %>
...
<%= text_field_tag(:q, params[:q]) %>
```

*routes.rb*

```
resources :spaces
resource :space, only: [:show]
```

*models/space.rb*

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Space < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end
Space.import
```

*controllers/spaces_controller.rb*

```
def show
if params[:q].present?
  @space = Space.search(params[:q].split.join(' AND '))
else
  @space = []
end
end
```

The error is:
[image: Search error]

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I found on elasticsearch-model's gem github page, the problem is you are calling `name` method on Elasticsearch Response object. You should call it on result documents.

Docs say:

```
response = Article.search 'fox dogs'
response.results.first._source.title # => "Quick brown fox"
```

so in your case it will be:

```
response = Space.search(params[:q].split.join(' AND '))    
@space = response.results.first._source
```